# FME: how to replace a character at a specific index?

Tags: fme-form, string

Suppose I've a string `foo`,

How can I change the 3rd character (identified by its **index**) ?

The Ruby equivalent would be

```ruby
# Define the variable string and assign the value 'bar'
string    = 'foo'     #=> 'foo'

# Change the string's character at index 2 to 'Z'
string[2] = 'Z'

# Output the string variable to see changes
string                #=> 'foZ'
```

I've tried using `SubString(@Value(my_string), 2, 1)` with replacement text set to 'Z', but it outputs `'fZZ'` (replacing all occurences of the value of the character at the specified index).

I could archive it by using regular expressions, though it'd be an overkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two substring commands to get the start of the string, miss out the third character and replace with 'Z', and then a final substring to add the remaining characters:

```
@Substring(@Value(foo),0,2)Z@Substring(@Value(foo),3,-1)
```

Note: tested works in FME 2017 AttributeManager.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Can I translate this part `Z@Substring(@Value(foo),3,-1)` as _"replace the 3rd until the last characters with "Z""_ ? I'll try it out once I've access to our FME server

Comment: Works like a charm ! My mate prefers the `Right()` method, but it's the same logic. Thanks again